# How to record logscope use Serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I use Serilog to record [logscope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#log-scopes) follow [this document](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#pushing-properties-to-the-iloggert), but it not work.

If I configuration the outputTemplate's value with `{Properites}`, can record the logscope but it also record all the event properties:

```json
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

output:

```
[22:35:03 INF] This is a log message{SourceContext="APIs.Controllers.HomeController", name="eason", ActionId="45b8843d-dd51-4f2b-bb7b-1e12a082b29a", ActionName="APIs.Controllers.HomeController.Health (APIs)", RequestId="0HMJ4RJFPK2CL:00000002", RequestPath="/Home", ConnectionId="0HMJ4RJFPK2CL", Scope=["This is a log scope, name:eason"]}
[22:35:03 INF] This is another log message{SourceContext="APIs.Controllers.HomeController", name="eason", ActionId="45b8843d-dd51-4f2b-bb7b-1e12a082b29a", ActionName="APIs.Controllers.HomeController.Health (APIs)", RequestId="0HMJ4RJFPK2CL:00000002", RequestPath="/Home", ConnectionId="0HMJ4RJFPK2CL", Scope=["This is a log scope, name:eason"]}
```

I want to out log message like this :

```
[22:35:03 INF] This is a log message{Scope=["This is a log scope, name:eason"]}
[22:35:03 INF] This is another log message{Scope=["This is a log scope, name:eason"]}
```

How do I do?
I use ASP.NET Core 6 with `Serilog.AspNetCore` 5.0.0

```cs
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
   // doesn't work
    // cfg.Enrich.FromLogContext();
});
```

record log:

```cs
using var scope = _logger.BeginScope("This is a log scope, name:{name}", "eason");
_logger.LogInformation("This is a log message");
_logger.LogInformation("This is another log message");
```

Configuration:

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "",
          "encoding": "System.Text.Encoding::UTF8",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2097152,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 10,
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

reference:
[Formatting Output](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)

Comment: `{Properties}` is all properties in the log event that are not already used in the rest of the template. So, if you add `Scope={Scope}` and remove the Properties bit, it will look more like what you want...